# Read PayPass with Mifare-reader

Tags: mifare

Is it possible to read some identification information of PayPass card with Mifare-reader?

I don't need any private or bank financial information to read from PayPass card. I need it only to identity different cards.

Comment: You can read the ATR of the card and from ATR you can idetify the card...

Comment: @vikky, how can I do this? Can you give me any instructions, sources, information, etc? I try to use regular mifare reader, but reader don't see any PayPass card.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library named "Winscard".you should use it.

Win32 API for communicating with smartcards within Windows platform in form SCardXXX.Similar implementation for Linux is developed under Muscle project as PC/SC Lite API. We will work with in Windows platform. Following functions will be used:

- SCardEstablishContext
- SCardListReaders
- SCardConnect
- SCardReconnect
- SCardDisconnect
- SCardReleaseContext
- SCardTransmit